How should I mitigate mold found in bathroom renovation?
We moved into our new house and have begun to renovate the bathroom. The bath that was there had been leaking, as well as the toilet. As expected - when we removed the plasterboard there was black mould behind it where the leak was. As a result, there is some residual mould on the timbers, the carpenter was happy with the wood and did not feel it affected the integrity in anyway.
However, my concern is when we put up new plasterboards and plaster the wall again that the mould will continue to grow. Has anyone any experience with this and any advice? I have contacted a mould specialist and they seem to think the best course of action is to get a spray treatment however, I think my partner thinks it is overkill.

Welcome. Have you searched? There are many existing questions on this topic.
